# How to create date range slicer from start/end dates of table instances?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables - the first contains path IDs, each with a start date, and an end date.  The second contains work item IDs, each with a created date, and a closed date.

I would like a way to select a path ID and have it display two tables, one with all work items created during that range and one with work items with closed dates within that time range.

I am currently doing this with two separate slicers, one for created date and one for closed date, and manually entering the time ranges for the paths that I want to look at, but I do not believe this is the optimal solution.

Example tables below:

Paths

```
    Path                Start Date           End Date

    P1/1                 1/1/2000            4/3/2000

    P1/2                 4/4/2000            8/7/2000                          

    P2/1                 8/8/2000           12/12/2000
```

Work Items

```
 Work Item ID          Created Date        Closed Date

      1                  1/2/2000           3/20/2000

      2                  4/5/2000           8/4/2000

      3                  3/2/2000           9/22/2000

      4                  7/5/2000          11/14/2000

      5                  1/2/2000           3/2/2000

      6                  9/5/2000          10/24/2000
```

Desired output when selecting P1/2:

Created during P1/2

```
  Work Item ID        Created Date

        2               4/5/2000

        4               7/5/2000
```

Closed during P1/2

```
  Work Item ID        Date Closed

       2               8/4/2000
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just look at the min of the start dates and max of the end dates for the paths you've selected.

Something along these lines should work even if you have multiple paths selected:

```
Created Date =
VAR WorkItemCreated = MAX ( 'Work Items'[Created Date] )
RETURN 
    IF ( WorkItemCreated >= MIN ( Paths[Start Date] ) &&
         WorkItemCreated <= MAX ( Paths[End Date] ),
         WorkItemCreated )
```

If the condition doesn't hold, it returns a blank and that row should be suppressed.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a ton!  For use of understanding what is going on here, why use the MAX() function when defining the variable?  I notice that it IS necessary, but also makes it so that there is a "total" row at the bottom of the chart that shows the most recent work item created date

Comment: Also, because this measure returns a date instead of an item ID, I am unable to count how many items of each type I have, any idea how to combat that issue?

Comment: Since it's a measure you need to use an aggregate function instead of a raw column. I chose `MAX` but `MIN` or `SELECTEDVALUE` would also work.